# Load custom tensorflow graph in the demo android application

Tags: android, tensorflow, deep-learning, training-data

I'm new with tensorflow and I'm following [this tutorial in youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gj0iyo265bc&list=PLOU2XLYxmsIIuiBfYad6rFYQU_jL2ryal) then I'm trying to train my own graph with the tensorflow deep learning method (using retrain.py file). I'have as result 2 files: one for labels and the other for the graph.
I'm trying to replace those two files with the same ones in [the tensorflow demo application for android](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android), but this didn't work for me.

I have read a bit about tensorflow on their website, but I found it complex for me as a beginner. Anyone can explain the problem to me please ???.